Delete files in Multiple Folders older than 30 days
I have a root directory: /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT
inside of that directory, I have 17 other directories

/opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/1

/opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/2

/opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/etc

/opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/17


Inside of those directories is files (no other directories)
I would like to delete the files that are older than 30 days, but NOT delete those last directories  (1, 2, etc, 17)
I have tried:
find /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/*/*.* -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \;

(there is a * between //. -mtime)
but I get "No such file or directory"
Any ideas?

You can use the -type f option, this should work : find /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/ -type f -mtime +30 -exec rm {} \; It will only remove files older than 30 days. You don't have to add wildcards with find.

Does that *.* mean you only want to delete files with at least one . in their name (other than at the start).

@admstg   I tried your suggestion after a short amount of time, I am not able to go into those directories to see if it worked.   I cancel out of the line, then I am able to access the directories, but the files are still there

@StéphaneChazelas  the . was meant to delete all the files, no matter the extention

First note that -mtime +30 selects files whose age rounded down to an integer number of days is strictly greater than 30, so that's files that are 31 days old or older. Same applies for the m+30 glob qualifier of zsh.
If you want to select files that have not been modified in the last 30 days (well, 30 ✕ 24 ✕ 60 ✕ 60 ✕ 1,000,000,000 nano-Unix-seconds before find was started and looked at the clock), you need -mtime +29 or with FreeBSD find -mtime +30d or with GNU find ! -newermt '30 days ago'
Also note that shell globs don't include hidden files (those whose name starts with .) by default and Unix is not MSDOS, . is not otherwise (other than at the start for those hidden files for some applications such as ls and shell globs) special in file names, *.* matches on files whose name contains at least one . just like *x* matches on files whose name contains at least one x.
Also note that in Unix, directory is one of many types of files. Other types of files include regular files (maybe the ones you had in mind when you mentioned file), symlinks, device files, fifos...
To delete the regular files (hidden or not, whether their name contains a . or not) not modified within the last 30 days two levels down /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT, with a few find implementations including GNU find, you could do:
find -H /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT \
  -mindepth 2 \
  -maxdepth 2 \
  -mtime +29 \
  -type f \
  -delete

POSIXly, that could be:
LC_ALL=C find -H /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT \
  -path '/opt/abc/logs/*/*' \
  -prune \
  -mtime +29 \
  -type f \
  -exec rm -f {} +

With zsh, that would be just:
rm -f /opt/abc/logs/EXPORT/*/*(NDm+29.)

If it's any file other than those of type directory you want to remove, you can replace -type f with ! -type d or zsh's . glob qualifier with ^/.

Thank you Stéphane Chazelas   Worked great
